# setting up drone agents to have custom /dev/shm

Tags: drone.io, tmpfs

The default drone-agent in 0.5 has a fixed size /dev/shm but I'd like to customise the size of this to be about 1GB.

Is this possible? I tried mounting the host's /dev/shm but that is ignored.

I am quite happy for the /dev/shm to be thrown away after the build but I would expect it to remain persistent within a stage, e.g. all commands in `build:` should see the same mounted /dev/shm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drone supports the `shm_size` parameter in the `.drone.yml` file. This is modeled after the Docker compose [specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/cpushares-cpuquota-cpuset-domainname-hostname-ipc-macaddress-memlimit-memswaplimit-oomscoreadj-privileged-readonly-restart-shmsize-stdinopen-tty-user-workingdir), of which Drone is a super-set.

The `shm_size` is customized per container:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: golang
    commands:
      - go build
      - go test
    shm_size: 1024000000
```

Note that setting this variable also requires the build to be trusted. This is controlled in the repository settings screen in Drone, and can be toggled by a Drone administrator.

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with this setting and it was community contributed. You may want to get in touch with [olymk2](https://github.com/olymk2) who authored the [pull request](https://github.com/drone/drone/pull/1801) to add this setting to Drone.